# What treatment can a pointer undergo and still be valid?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

Which of the following ways of treating and trying to recover a C pointer, is guaranteed to be valid?

1) Cast to void pointer and back

```
int f(int *a) {
    void *b = a;
    a = b;
    return *a;
}
```

2) Cast to appropriately sized integer and back

```
int f(int *a) {
    uintptr_t b = a;
    a = (int *)b;
    return *a;
}
```

3) A couple of trivial integer operations

```
int f(int *a) {
    uintptr_t b = a;
    b += 99;
    b -= 99;
    a = (int *)b;
    return *a;
}
```

4) Integer operations nontrivial enough to obscure provenance, but which will nonetheless leave the value unchanged

```
int f(int *a) {
    uintptr_t b = a;
    char s[32];
    // assume %lu is suitable
    sprintf(s, "%lu", b);
    b = strtoul(s);
    a = (int *)b;
    return *a;
}
```

5) More indirect integer operations that will leave the value unchanged

```
int f(int *a) {
    uintptr_t b = a;
    for (uintptr_t i = 0;; i++)
        if (i == b) {
            a = (int *)i;
            return *a;
        }
}
```

Obviously case 1 is valid, and case 2 surely must be also. On the other hand, I came across a post by Chris Lattner - which I unfortunately can't find now - saying something similar to case 5 is *not* valid, that the standard licenses the compiler to just compile it to an infinite loop. Yet each case looks like an unobjectionable extension of the previous one.

Where is the line drawn between a valid case and an invalid one?

Added based on discussion in comments: while I still can't find the post that inspired case 5, I don't remember what type of pointer was involved; in particular, it might have been a function pointer, which might be why that case demonstrated invalid code whereas my case 5 is valid code.

Second addition: okay, here's another source that says there is a problem, and this one I do have a link to. https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cerberus/notes30.pdf - the discussion about pointer provenance - says, and backs up with evidence, that no, if the compiler loses track of where a pointer came from, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: With regards to `assume %lu is suitable` - `%lu` is indeed not guaranteed to be suitable on every platform. In particularly on platforms which consist of: 1. 64-bit HW. 2. A compiler which treats `long` differently from `long long`.

Comment: Case 5 does not give an infinite loop - unless the compiler is broken, of course.  The loop completion might take enough time to be observable, depending on the value of `a`, particularly if compiling without optimisation.   But a compiler could also simply optimise the loop out completely.

Comment: I suspect you misremembered what Chris Lattner said. Case 5 can't be infinite loop as `uintrptr_t` should be able to represent all possible values that a data pointer value can be (unless the whole `[u]intrptr_t` mechanism is totally broken). You'd better find the *actual example* where he said so.

Comment: @P.P. I still haven't managed to find the actual example, but 'data pointer' reminds me of something - I don't remember the exact type of the pointer in the example, it might have been a function pointer. Does that make a difference here?

Comment: @rwallace `[u]intptr_t` can't store function pointers (they are defined only for data pointers). So, yes, in case of converting function pointers to [u]intptr_t it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @P.P. `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to store any valid `void*` (and only) pointer. And any pointer can be converted to `void*`... So.. A function pointer can be casted to void and then to `uintptr_t`, right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The latter doesn't follow from the former. A `void*` isn't guaranteed to hold a function pointer.

Comment: @P.P. Indeed. Missed that point. Though the standard guarantees *any* pointer is convertible to an integer type, it is not defining this type for function pointers..

Comment: Integer operations that completely obscure provenance are probably not as much of a problem as those involving integers that a compiler can see are "unrelated" but actually point to the same object.  I'm not sure if there are any useful rules about what cases most compilers will reliably handle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

#### Example 1

Valid, by §6.5.16.1, even without an explicit cast.

#### Example 2

The `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` types are optional.  Assigning a pointer to an integer requires an explicit cast (§6.5.16.1), although gcc and clang will only warn you if you don’t have one.  With those caveats, the round-trip conversion is valid by §7.20.1.4.  **ETA:** John Bellinger brings up that the behavior is only specified when you do an intermediate cast to `void*` both ways.  However, both gcc and clang allow the direct conversion as a documented extension.

#### Example 3

Safe, but only because you’re using unsigned arithmetic, which cannot overflow, and are therefore guaranteed to get the same object representation back.  An `intptr_t` could overflow!  If you want to do pointer arithmetic safely, you can convert any kind of pointer to `char*` and then add or subtract offsets within the same structure or array.  Remember, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.  **ETA:** The standard guarantees that the two pointers compare equal, but your link to Chisnall *et al.* gives examples where compilers nevertheless assume the two pointers do not alias each other.

#### Example 4

**Always, always, always** check for buffer overflows whenever you read from and especially whenever you write to a buffer!  If you can mathematically prove that overflow cannot happen by static analysis?  Then write out the assumptions that justify that, explicitly, and `assert()` or `static_assert()` that they haven’t changed.  Use `snprintf()`, not the deprecated, unsafe `sprintf()`!  If you remember nothing else from this answer, remember that!

To be absolutely pedantic, the portable way to do this would be to use the format specifiers in `<inttypes.h>` and define the buffer length in terms of the maximum value of any pointer representation.  In the real world, you would print pointers out with the `%p` format.

The answer to the question you intended to ask is yes, though: all that matters is that you get back the same object representation.  Here’s a less contrived example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 1;
    const uintptr_t u = (uintptr_t)(void*)&i;
    uintptr_t v;

    memcpy( &v, &u, sizeof(v) );
    int* const p = (int*)(void*)v;

    assert(p == &i);
    *p = 2;
    printf( "%d = %d.\n", i, *p ); 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

All that matter are the bits in your object representation.  This code also follows the strict aliasing rules in §6.5.  It compiles and runs fine on the compilers that gave Chisnall *et al* trouble.

#### Example 5

This works, same as above.

One extremely pedantic footnote that will never ever be relevant to your coding: some obsolete esoteric hardware has one’s-complement or sign-and-magnitude representation of signed integers, and on these, there might be a distinct value of negative zero that might or might not trap.  On some CPUs, this might be a valid pointer or null pointer representation distinct from positive zero.  And on some CPUs, positive and negative zero might compare equal.

#### PS

The standard says:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

Furthermore, if the two array objects are consecutive rows of the same multidimensional array, one past the end of the first row is a valid pointer to the start of the next row.  Therefore, even a pathological implementation that deliberately sets out to cause as many bugs as the standard allows could only do so if your manipulated pointer compares equal to the address of an array object, in which case the implementation might in theory decide to interpret it as one-past-the-end of some other array object instead.

The intended behavior is clearly that the pointer comparing equal both to `&array1+1` and to `&array2` is equivalent to both: it means to let you compare it to addresses within `array1` or dereference it to get `array2[0]`.  However, the Standard does not actually say that.

#### PPS

The standards committee [has addressed some of these issues](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2263.htm) and proposes that the C standard explicitly add language about pointer provenance. This would nail down whether a conforming implementation is allowed to assume that a pointer created by bit manipulation does not alias another pointer.

Specifically, the proposed corrigendum would introduce pointer provenance and allow pointers with different provenance not to compare equal. It would also introduce a `-fno-provenance` option, which would guarantee that any two pointers compare equal if and only if they have the same numeric address. (As discussed above, two object pointers that compare equal alias each other.)

Comment: @supercat I respectfully disagree with that interpretation. Any pointer that compares equal to the address of, at minimum, an object that is not an array object must, by Standard, be a pointer to the same object. Array object is not a synonym for object.

Comment: @supercat I do not agree, for several reasons. The simplest: The "pointer to one past the end of one array object" loophole only applies to "a pointer to the start of a different array object." If you have a pointer to any other kind of object, the standard guarantees that any pointer that compares equal to it is a pointer to the same object (unless there is some other undefined behavior in the program).

Comment: @supercat No. The standard requires that, if `&foo.bar[7]` compares equal to `&foo.boz`, both are pointers to the same object, `foo.baz`, and both are also one past the end of `foo.bar`. it can be dereferenced to access `foo.boz`, compared to pointers within `foo.bar`, and can also have offsets of up to 7 subtracted from it. Exactly like how, if you declare `some_type a[2][1];`, `&(a[0][0]) + 1 == &a[1][0]` and both pointers are equivalent.

Comment: @supercat The standard says, "The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))". Therefore, a pointer one-past-the-end of the first row of an array and a pointer to the first element of the second row of the array are equivalent, according to the standard.
.

Comment: @supercat This is getting far into the weeds, but, bottom line: the Standard guarantees that a round-trip conversion of an object pointer or a one-past-the-end pointer is usable in the same way. It is possible that a pointer to an array object, and only an array object, might compare equal to a pointer to one-past-the-end of another array. In this case, an implementation is **theoretically** allowed to chose one of the two interpretations to be valid and not the other. But none ever will

Comment: My example was `&(a[0][n-1])+1`, not `a[0][n]`.

Comment: @supercat You seem to be getting stuck on the idea that a valid pointer to an object can also be a valid pointer one-past-the-end of an array. It can, but that's irrelevant. Whatever else you can also do with an object pointer that's been converted to integer and back, the Standard unequivocally guarantees that it is a valid pointer to the same object as the original pointer.

Comment: Does C17 add language indicating that round-trip conversion of a pointer through integer type will yield a pointer which can be used in ways equivalent to the original pointer, or does it--like N1570, merely guarantee that the resulting pointer will "compare equal to" the original?

Comment: @supercat Since the standard says that two object pointers that compare equal reference the same object, the premise of your question is misguided.

Comment: @supercat The proposed corrigendum would remove the guarantee that pointers with the same bit patterns but different provenance compare equal (as comparing equal guarantees they alias each other). It also introduces an `-fno-provenance` option, under which any two pointers with the same type and object representation must compare equal.

Comment: @supercat The standard guarantees that `p` and `q` reference the same object. I must be missing your point.

Comment: @supercat I'm on the road, but several places. One of which I quoted in my answer. The standard does not allow the kind of pathological behavior you're thinking of. (Although there might be a strict-aliasing violation.)

Comment: @supercat Both `p` and `q` in your example point within the same array object. I would take another look at the definition of array subscripts. The two pointers are equivalent.

Comment: @supercat No, that doesn’t apply to the `p`/`q` example. You’ve spent a lot of comments on a hypothetical scenario where I don’t think your interpretation of the standard is correct. It also is not at all similar to the actual corner cases where real compilers have assumed pointers with different provenance don’t alias.

Comment: @supercat [I’m a little busy to revive this, but here’s a specific reference for you.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102)

Comment: If the only thing actually required by the Standard is that pointers compare equal, that would allow conforming implementations intended for various purposes to make aliasing assumptions that would be appropriate for such purposes, even if it would be possible to construct programs where such assumptions would be incorrect.  The fact that implementations can be conforming without having to support dereferencing in any particular situation in no way implies that implementations shouldn't allow dereferencing in cases that might be needed to serve their intended purposes.

Comment: Since the people designing implementations should be in a better position than the authors of the Standard to know what purposes their implementations are intended to serve, and what cases must be handled to serve those purposes, I think the authors of the Standard intended to defer to implementers' judgment on such matters.  Such deference would allow a capricious implementer to make an implementation that's unsuitable for any purpose, but the authors of the Standard recognized that possibility in the rationale and did not think it should be a problem.

Comment: @supercat Your premise about "the only thing actually required by the Standard" is incorrect. There are real-world cases where compilers assume that pointers with different provenance cannot alias each other, causing bugs. Those are totally unrelated. I'd like to request that you take any further comments in this vein to chat and this conversation be cleaned out of the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Cast to void pointer and back

This yields a valid pointer equal to the original.  Paragraph 6.3.2.3/1 of the standard is clear on this:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

---

> 2) Cast to appropriately sized integer and back
>
> 3) A couple of trivial integer operations
>
> 4) Integer operations nontrivial enough to obscure provenance, but which will nonetheless leave the value unchanged
>
> 5) More indirect integer operations that will leave the value unchanged
>
> [...] Obviously case 1 is valid, and case 2 surely must be also. On the other hand, I came across a post by Chris Lattner - which I unfortunately can't find now - saying case 5 is not valid, that the standard licenses the compiler to just compile it to an infinite loop.

C does require a cast when converting either way between pointers and integers, and you have omitted some of those in your example code.  In that sense your examples (2) - (5) are all non-conforming, but for the rest of this answer I'll pretend the needed casts are there.

Still, being very pedantic, all of these examples have implementation-defined behavior, so they are not *strictly* conforming.  On the other hand, "implementation-defined" behavior is still defined behavior; whether that means your code is "valid" or not depends on what you mean by that term.  In any event, what code the compiler might emit for any of the examples is a separate matter.

These are the relevant provisions of the standard from section 6.3.2.3 (emphasis added):

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, ***the result is implementation-defined***, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, ***the result is implementation-defined***. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

The definition of `uintptr_t` is also relevant to your particular example code.  The standard describes it this way (C2011, 7.20.1.4/1; emphasis added):

> an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer ***to void*** can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer ***to void***, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer.

You are converting back and forth between `int *` and `uintptr_t`.  `int *` is not `void *`, so 7.20.1.4/1 does not apply to these conversions, and the behavior is implementation-defined per section 6.3.2.3.

Suppose, however, that you convert back and forth via an intermediate `void *`:

```
uintptr_t b = (uintptr_t)(void *)a;
a = (int *)(void *)b;
```

On an implementation that provides `uintptr_t` (which is optional), that would make your examples (2 - 5) all strictly conforming.  In that case, the result of the integer-to-pointer conversions depends only on the value of the `uintptr_t` object, not on how that value was obtained.

As for the claims you attribute to Chris Lattner, they are substantially incorrect.  If you have represented them accurately, then perhaps they reflect a confusion between implementation-defined behavior and *un*defined behavior.  If the code exhibited undefined behavior then the claim might hold some water, but that is not, in fact, the case.

Regardless of how its value was obtained, `b` has a definite value of type `uintptr_t`, and the loop must eventually increment `i` to that value, at which point the `if` block will run.  In principle, the implementation-defined behavior of a conversion from `uintptr_t` directly to `int *` could be something crazy such as skipping the next statement (thus causing an infinite loop), but such behavior is entirely implausible.  Every implementation you ever meet will either fail at that point, or store some value in variable `a`, and then, if it didn't crash, it will execute the `return` statement.

Comment: Good catch on the missing casts. Assuming we insert those as necessary, I see what you're saying, and it's what I would hope to be the case. However, I've now found another source saying there is a problem, and this one I do have a link to - see second added paragraph - https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cerberus/notes30.pdf

Comment: Well, the conversions between integer and pointer are valid simple assignments even without the explicit cast, but compilers will warn about them and we want to suppress warning messages so the real bugs stand out.  Good catch on the standard only guaranteeing round-trip conversion by way of `void*`.

Comment: The Standard is a bit sloppy with regard to `uintptr_t`; it guarantees that a round-trip conversion through uintptr_t will yield a pointer which compares equal to the original, but says nothing about whether the pointer can be used in the same ways as any or all pointers to which it would compare equal.

Comment: Not so, @Davislor.  Read [section 6.5.16.1/1 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1), describing the constraints on the operands of the simple assignment operator.  Assignment of integer to pointer or pointer to integer is a constraint violation.  Therefore, not only is the behavior of such an assignment undefined, but conforming compilers are required to emit a diagnostic about it.

Comment: @supercat, the standard does allow that values that compare equal may have different representations, but it also holds that "Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result" (C2011, 6.2.6.1/8).  Does that not indeed say that the value resulting from round-tripping a pointer through `uintptr_t` can serve in all ways as the original pointer value can do?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Consider: `int x,y, *p1=&x+1, *p2=y;`  Even if the addresses of p1 and p2 happen to be equal, a compiler would not be required to recognize use of p1[0] to access y, nor p2[-1] to access x.  While it would make sense that if (uintptr_t)p1 and (uintptr_t)p2 yield the same value, which is then cast back to an `int* p3`, then p3 should be usable to access either x or y, nothing in the Standard actually *says* that.

Comment: I'm not buying it, @supercat.  The result of evaluating an operation in a conforming C program is determined by the types and values of the operands.  The standard says exactly how that works -- it does not qualify that on how the values were obtained, nor does it need to do so, nor indeed *can* it do so exhaustively.  Your example does exhibit undefined behavior as you say (*i.e.* it does not conform), but the OP's does conform.  Your example would conform too, however, if dereferencing `p1` were conditional on `p1` being equal to `p2`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Okay, so it isn’t simple assignment and I should change my wording to say that the way I’ve always done it is more than just good style.  I originally wrote that the cast was needed, then was surprised that I didn’t see anything in the standard requiring the explicit cast.  Now I’ll have to change that part of my answer back.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Compilers used to operate under an execution model where the value of every object whose address has ever been taken will be represented by the bits stored at that address.  Various aliasing rules have changed the model.  The Standard makes very clear that given `int foo[2][3];`, evaluating the address `foo[0]+3` will be defined behavior, and that address will compare equal to `foo[1]`, but an attempt to access `foo[0][3]` is Undefined Behavior.  It is very clear on the latter point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: IMHO, the proper way to have enabled the optimizations that would come from making `foo[0][3]` UB would be to have said that arrays do *not* decay into pointers when used as the operand of `[]`, but are instead fed to a form of `[]` that operates directly on arrays.  That would allow `*(foo[0]+x)` to access any element within `foo` even if `foo[0][x]` would be limited to accessing the first row.  That's not what the Standard says, however.

Comment: @supercat, evidently the standard is not as clear on this point as you assert.  Moreover, you're focusing on the case of a pointer to one position past the end of an array, but that's not the OP's case.  I am well aware of [paragraph 6.5.6/8 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8), which discusses that case, but I am not convinced that it means quite what you claim.  Perhaps you would be interested in formulating your argument into an answer?  With supporting citations to the standard?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I just added an answer.  Most apparent ambiguities in the Standard are actually cases where the authors of the Standard decided to treat something as a Quality of Implementation issue.  If it's obvious that almost all implementations should process something the same way, but it's conceivable that an implementation for some platform might have a good reason for doing something else in some obscure case where the normal behavior wouldn't be useful, the authors of the Standard would have seen no reason to forbid such alternative behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

Because different application fields require the ability to manipulate pointers in different ways, and because the best implementations for some purposes may be totally unsuitable for some others, the C Standard treats the support (or lack thereof) for various kinds of manipulations as a *Quality of Implementation* issue.  In general, people writing an implementation for a particular application field should be more familiar than the authors of the Standard with what features would be useful to programmers in that field, and people making a bona fide effort to produce quality implementations suitable for writing applications in that field will support such features whether the Standard requires them to or not.

In the pre-Standard language invented by Dennis Ritchie, all pointers of a particular type that were identified the same address were equivalent.  If any sequence of operations on a pointer would end up producing another pointer of the same type that identified the same address, that pointer would--essentially by definition--be equivalent to the first.  The C Standard specifies some situations, however, where pointers can identify the same location in storage and be indistinguishable from each other without being equivalent.  For example, given:

```
int foo[2][4] = {0};
int *p = foo[0]+4, *q=foo[1];
```

both `p` and `q` will compare equal to each other, and to `foo[0]+4`, and to `foo[1]`.  On the other hand, despite the fact that evaluation of `p[-1]` and `q[0]` would have defined behavior, evaluation of `p[0]` or `q[-1]` would invoke UB.  Unfortunately, while the Standard makes clear that `p` and `q` would not be equivalent, it does nothing to clarify whether performing various sequences of operations on e.g. `p` will yield a pointer that is usable in all cases where `p` was usable, a pointer that's usable in all cases where *either* `p` or `q` would be usable, a pointer that's only usable in cases where `q` would be usable, or a pointer that's only usable in cases where *both* `p` and `q` would be usable.

Quality implementations intended for low-level programming should generally process pointer manipulations other than those involving `restrict` pointers in a way that would yield a pointer that would be usable in any case where a pointer that compares equal to it could usable.  Unfortunately, the Standard provides no means by which a program can determine if it's being processed by a quality implementations that is suitable for low-level programming and refuse to run if it isn't, so most forms of systems programming must rely upon quality implementations processing certain actions in documented manner characteristic of the environment even when the Standard would impose no requirements.

Incidentally, even if the normal constructs for manipulating pointers wouldn't have any way of creating pointers where the principles of equivalence shouldn't apply, some platforms may define ways of creating "interesting" pointers.  For example, if an implementation that would normally trap operations on null pointers were run on in an environment where it might sometimes be necessary to access an object at address zero, it might define a special syntax for creating a pointer that could be used to access any address, including zero, within the context where it was created.  A "legitimate pointer to address zero" would likely compare equal to a null pointer (even though they're not equivalent), but performing a round-trip conversion to another type and back would likely convert what had been a legitimate pointer to address zero into a null pointer.  If the Standard had mandated that a round-trip conversion of *any* pointer must yield one that's usable in the same way as the original, that would require that the compiler omit null traps on any pointers that could have been produced in such a fashion, even if they would far more likely have been produced by round-tripping a null pointer.

Incidentally, from a practical perspective, "modern" compilers, even in `-fno-strict-aliasing`, will sometimes attempt to track provenance of pointers through pointer-integer-pointer conversions in such a way that pointers produced by casting equal integers may sometimes be assumed incapable of aliasing.

For example, given:

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern int x[],y[];
int test(void)
{
    if (!x[0]) return 999;

    uintptr_t upx = (uintptr_t)x;
    uintptr_t upy = (uintptr_t)(y+1);

    //Consider code with and without the following line
    if (upx == upy) upy = upx;

    if ((upx ^ ~upy)+1) // Will return if upx != upy
        return 123;

    int *py = (int*)upy;
    *py += 1;
    return x[0];
}
```

In the absence of the marked line, gcc, icc, and clang will all assume--even when using `-fno-strict-aliasing`, that an operation on `*py` can't affect `*px`, even though the only way that code could be reached would be if `upx` and `upy` held the same value (meaning that both `px` and `py` were produced by casting the same `uintptr_t` value).  Adding the marked line causes icc and clang to recognize that px and py could identify the same object, but gcc assumes that the assignment can be optimized out, even though it should mean that `py` would be derived from `px`--a situation a quality compiler should have no trouble recognizing as implying possible aliasing.

I'm not sure what realistic benefit compiler writers expect from their efforts to track provenance of uintptr_t values, given that I don't see much purpose for doing such conversions outside of cases where the results of conversions may be used in "interesting" ways.  Given compiler behavior, however, I'm not sure I see any nice way to guarantee that conversions between integers and pointers will behave in a fashion consistent with the values involved.